Chocolatey was not upgrading package to the latest version until I manually specified the version
I am using Chocolatey v2.3.0 Professional on Windows 11. The package in question is Obsidian. I had Obsidian 1.6.7 installed. Attempting to upgrade it without any options resulted in chocolatey saying that v1.6.7 is the latest version available based on my sources.
Here was the output of the first run:
> choco upgrade obsidian
Chocolatey v2.3.0 Professional
Upgrading the following packages:
obsidian
By upgrading, you accept licenses for the packages.
obsidian v1.6.7 is the latest version available based on your source(s).

Chocolatey upgraded 0/1 packages.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).

To get the latest version, I had to run choco upgrade obsidian --version 1.7.4. I don't want to have to manually do this for every package: ideally I could rely on running choco upgrade all to get the latest versions of everything. So I'm wondering if anyone knows anything about this, like maybe if I have to configure my sources or something.
Here is the info that was returned about Obsidian from choco info obsidian before I did the proper upgrade:
> choco info obsidian
Chocolatey v2.3.0 Professional
obsidian 1.6.7 [Approved] Downloads cached for licensed users
 Title: Obsidian | Published: 7/19/2024
 Package approved as a trusted package on Sep 29 2024 08:35:21.
 Package testing status: Passing on Jul 19 2024 03:32:50.
 Number of Downloads: 155796 | Downloads for this version: 11582
 Package url https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/obsidian/1.6.7
 Chocolatey Package Source: https://github.com/jonasw234/au-packages/tree/master/obsidian
 Package Checksum: 'Qc2ixBe/a0XkH5ugiS/RZBVa2xRYnh7NrhEO11Oa3M6yko4IOc2EJC4I/wUMTKrOIPHWnT9oDsE4W0EaxIh/JA==' (SHA512)
 Tags: markdown editor note keeping wiki
 Software Site: https://obsidian.md/
 Software License: https://obsidian.md/license
 Issues: https://forum.obsidian.md/c/bug-reports
 Summary: Obsidian is a powerful knowledge base that works on top of a local folder of plain text Markdown files.
 Description: # A second brain, for you, forever.

  Obsidian is a powerful knowledge base that works on top of a local folder of plain text Markdown files.

  ![Obsidian](https://obsidian.md/images/screenshot.png "Obsidian")

  The human brain is non-linear: we jump from idea to idea, all the time. Your second brain should work the same.

  In Obsidian, making and following \[\[connections\]\] is frictionless. Tend to your notes like a gardener; at the end of the day, sit back and marvel at your own knowledge graph.

  Note-taking is incredibly personal. Tried every app, but there's always something not quite right? You deserve better.

  Obsidian is built to be extensible. With [22 core plugins](https://publish.obsidian.md/help/Plugins/List%20of%20plugins) and [116 community plugins](https://help.obsidian.md/Advanced+topics/Third-party+plugins#Discover+and+install+community+plugins), set up your own toolkit and get running in minutes.

  You'll even be able to install third party plugins or build your own once Obsidian reaches v1.0. Sky's the limit.

  In our age when cloud services can [shut](https://techcrunch.com/2013/07/31/evernote-competitor-catch-com-shuts-down-its-note-taking-apps-company-heading-in-different-direction/) [down](https://www.theverge.com/2014/5/22/5741602/one-time-evernote-pinterest-rival-springpad-to-close-its-doors), [get](https://gadgets.ndtv.com/apps/news/microsoft-to-do-new-features-wunderlist-shuts-down-2224833) [bought](https://www.theverge.com/2012/3/12/2865638/twitter-acquires-posterous-blogging-platform), or [change privacy policy](https://techcrunch.com/2016/12/14/evernotes-new-privacy-policy-allows-employees-to-read-your-notes/) any day, the last thing you want is proprietary formats and data lock-in.

  With Obsidian, your data sits in a local folder. Never leave your life's work held hostage in the cloud again.

  Plain text Markdown also gives you the unparalleled interoperability to use any kind of sync, encryption, or data processing that works with plain text files.

  *To change the installation directory* use the parameter `--install-arguments='"/D=C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Obsidian"'`
  *Please note* This is an automatically updated package.  If the package is outdated for more than two days, please [let me know](https://github.com/jonasw234/au-packages/issues).
 Release Notes: https://forum.obsidian.md/c/announcements

1 packages found.

Here's the output of the successful upgrade
> choco upgrade obsidian --version 1.7.4
Chocolatey v2.3.0 Professional
Upgrading the following packages:
obsidian
By upgrading, you accept licenses for the packages.

You have obsidian v1.6.7 installed. Version 1.7.4 is available based on your source(s).
Downloading package from source 'https://community.chocolatey.org/api/v2/'
Progress: Downloading obsidian 1.7.4... 100%

obsidian v1.7.4
obsidian package files upgrade completed. Performing other installation steps.
The package obsidian wants to run 'chocolateyInstall.ps1'.
Note: If you don't run this script, the installation will fail.
Note: To confirm automatically next time, use '-y' or consider:
choco feature enable -n allowGlobalConfirmation
Do you want to run the script?([Y]es/[A]ll - yes to all/[N]o/[P]rint): a

Downloading obsidian 64 bit
  from 'https://github.com/obsidianmd/obsidian-releases/releases/download/v1.7.4/Obsidian-1.7.4.exe'.
Progress: 100% - Completed download of 'Obsidian-1.7.4.exe' (239.87 MB).
Download of 'Obsidian-1.7.4.exe' (239.87 MB) completed.
Virus check: 0/66 scan engines flagged this assembly.
 Due to possible false positives we fail at 4 minimum positives.
 Virus scan engines indicate this file is probably safe. For details see
  https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/a4ca800e228de906a63c4d192d863336fbdb05cec4f6f300278331f39ff34e69/detection/f-a4ca800e228de906a63c4d192d863336fbdb05cec4f6f300278331f39ff34e69-1729115506
Installing Obsidian-1.7.4.exe...


UPDATED ANSWER
We have just deployed new aspects of the Chocolatey Community Repository infrastructure to address this issue.  If you are still seeing a problem with newly pushed packages, please reach out.
ORIGINAL ANSWER
This is a known issue with the Chocolatey Community Repository currently.
We recently switched to a new search system on the Chocolatey Community Repository, and when a new package version is pushed (in this case Obsidian 1.7.4 was pushed earlier this morning), it isn't immediately available in the cache of packages that the search system uses.
There is a new version of the Chocolatey Community Repository waiting to be deployed to address this problem, however, I can't speak to exactly when that will happen.
The workarounds for the moment are:

specify the specific package version as you are currently doing
wait a period of time until the cache that is used is updated

